# Please set env variable CHROME_BIN

Tags: environment-variables, chrome, node.js

```
> node node_modules/karma/bin/karma start test/karma.conf.js

INFO [karma]: Karma v0.12.30 server started at http://localhost:9876/
INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Chrome
ERROR [launcher]: Cannot start Chrome
    Can not find the binary google-chrome
    Please set env variable CHROME_BIN
```

OK, I appreciate this must be a gigantic nooby style question, but I am still in the process of attempting to migrate my life from Windows and every now and again something like this trips me up.

I am going through an [Angular JS tutorial](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial).

When attempting to run a series of test I am confronted with the above message.

The `/etc/environment` file now reads (note the Chromium ending):

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games/:/usr/bin/chromium-browser:"
```

I then ran

```
source /etc/environment
```

Restarted terminal and attempted the tests again, but I have the same result.

What is the error really telling me? Am I meant to set a new variable named `CHROME_BIN` and point this to `/usr/bin/chromium-browser`?

Comment: Try with `export CHROME_BIN=/usr/bin/chromium-browser` and see if the tests run OK.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Your node wants to start Chrome (or any browser) and use environment variables to set it out. Just export the variable along with the path pointing to the binary and it should work:

```
export CHROME_BIN=/usr/bin/chromium-browser
```

Now, actually it should just call `sensible-browser` instead of forcing you to do this.

Comment: Thank you, this is the correct answer for me.